# Ideals and Orders.

Tags: number-theory

I have question about orders in a number field $K$:

We defined an order of $K$ to be a subring of $\mathcal{O}_K$ (the Ring of Integers of $K$) which is as a free $\Bbb{Z}$-module of rank $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$.

We proved also that every (fractional) ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\Bbb{Z}$-module of rank $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$.

My question is: would this mean that every integral ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is an order?

Thanks.

Mohammed

Comment: No.  An ideal in a ring is not a subring of the ring unless the ideal is the whole ring: ideals and subrings are *different* concepts.  Unfortunately Dummit & Foote's abstract algebra book says otherwise, but when rings have a multiplicative identity (as they do in number theory), you should *not* consider ideals to be subrings. The even numbers are *not* a subring of the integers. See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/ringdefs.pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much, what should we call sets that have the same   properties of a Ring but have no multiplicative element? for example 2Z (i know we would call it an ideal of Z, but what would we call it as an independent set?).

Comment: @SimoSlimani It is called a Rng. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)

Comment: ah ok, thanks to both of you.

Comment: You should call $2\mathbf Z$ an *ideal* if you're working with $\mathbf Z$ as a ring. Don't go around calling $2\mathbf Z$ a "rng".  Cute labels aside, rngs are not important in number theory.

Comment: ........ok sir!